# Text hidden by 'before' css element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate something I saw on another site, but currently my before element is hiding my text. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

This is the example:

```css
body {margin: 20px;}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```

Comment: Please spellcheck your post title. By the way, `::before` (with two colons) is correct.

Comment: Is there any problem with using `z-index:-1;`, or somehow you skipped this solution  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a negative `z-index` to push that layer below the "parent".

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* this here */
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use z-index to see the text

```css
body {margin: 20px;}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index: -1` to :before pseudo element.

```css
body {margin: 20px;}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Add `z-index:-1;` in `#hello:before`.

```css
body {margin: 20px;}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by adding a `z-index: -1` on the before element

```css
body {margin: 20px;}

a {
  padding: 120px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#hello:before {
  background-color: #4541f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

#hello:hover::before {
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease, -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  transform: perspective(100px) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hello">Test</a>
```